# Prevent multiple instances of the same activity through navigation drawer

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer in few of the activities. I can use that to navigate to a given list of activities. Here, I have a problem. Suppose I'm at Activity X and through the navigation drawer, picked Activity X again. Then, another instance of the same activity gets created.

I tried using the `singleInstance` in the manifest for such activites, but then I'm getting another problem. Pressing back-button from such "singleInstance" activity leads me to the very first non-singleTask activity. It doesn't take me back to the actual previous activity.

How can I resolve that?

**UPDATE:**

Using `singleTop` instead of `singleInstance` did the thing for me. Also read [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en) article for more details on launch modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `singleTop` instead of `singleTask`

Comment: Please explain why that handles the issue so that future visitors to this question can also benefit from the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Put this attribute to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: Sorry, just a mistype in the question. I was using singleInstance only. mistyped the question. Updated it now.